# Ignore eslint errors during git pre-commit

Tags: javascript, git, eslint, package.json, pre-commit-hook

I would like to use eslint with git pre-commit hook, so it can fix errors automatically (at least what can be fixed automatically) and ignore other errors, so it doesn't block the commit itself.

The code from package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test-staged": "lint-staged"
},
"pre-commit": [
  "test-staged"
],
"lint-staged": {
  "*.{js,jsx}": [
    "eslint --config=config/.eslintrc --fix",
    "git add"
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think managed it to work:

```
"scripts": {
   "eslint-fix-force": "npm run eslint --fix || true",
   "test-staged": "lint-staged"
}

"lint-staged": {
  "*.{js,jsx}": [
    "eslint-fix-force",
    "git add"
  ]
}
```

You also need to have `lint-staged` in `dependencies` inside `package.json`